Dancing scene from another movie/video in "Silver Linings Playbook"
While working on their own performance Tiffany & Pat are watching a video, where two men are dancing on the table, then they jump down and continue dancing on the floor. I guess this scene is from another movie as I'm quite sure I've already seen it earlier. Does anybody now from which movie/video is this dancing scene taken?

It's the famous 'Moses Supposes' scene from Singin' in the Rain:



